# /var/log/messages - not compressing while rotating

Tags: linux, logs, syslog, logrotate

I'm trying to compress the messages cause its growing huge in size and there is not much space. I tried all from - [compress-messages](https://serverfault.com/questions/116201/logrotate-does-not-compress-var-log-messages/) - to compress the messages but its with

`glob finding old rotated logs failed`

My logrotate is similar to the one in the link

```
# cat logrotate-message; logrotate -d logrotate-message -f;ls -lrth /var/log/messages*
daily
rotate 7
create
dateext
dateformat .%Y%m%d
compress
notifempty
nomail
noolddir
/var/log/messages {
    rotate 5
    daily
    postrotate
        /bin/killall -HUP syslogd
    endscript
}
reading config file logrotate-message
Allocating hash table for state file, size 15360 B

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /var/log/messages  forced from command line (5 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/messages
  log needs rotating
rotating log /var/log/messages, log->rotateCount is 5
Converted ' .%Y%m%d' -> '.%Y%m%d'
dateext suffix '.20191024'
glob pattern '.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
glob finding old rotated logs failed
renaming /var/log/messages to /var/log/messages.20191024
creating new /var/log/messages mode = 0600 uid = 0 gid = 0
running postrotate script
running script with arg /var/log/messages: "
        /bin/killall -HUP syslogd
"
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
-rw------- 1 root root 1016K Sep 29 03:13 /var/log/messages-20190929
-rw------- 1 root root 1020K Oct  6 03:34 /var/log/messages-20191006
-rw------- 1 root root  2.2G Oct 23 11:31 /var/log/messages.20191023
-rw------- 1 root root  735M Oct 24 15:41 /var/log/messages
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What does `file /var/log/messages.20191023` return?

Comment: Like below
`# file /var/log/messages.20191023
/var/log/messages.20191023: ASCII text, with very long lines`

Comment: Ok, I thought for a while that it compressed it but didn't give it the `.gz` suffix.

Comment: Its not compressing, in the debug output its erroring like `glob finding old rotated logs failed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, your `logrotate` is failing because of missing log files. When you use `logrotate -d` you are getting verbose debug output but `logrotate does not do anything`. If you first do

```
logrotate -v logrotate-message -f
```

instead the force option, combined with verbose output will show you the operation of `-f` flag, which per `man logrotate` will create missing log files to prevent errors related to previous log files not being found.

You are not finding the 4 log archives because in the first two filenames you have a `-` where a `.` should be and the pattern regex fails because of it. Try correcting by hand or `logrotate -f` create it after deleting these first.

Also, your formatting of the specifc `messages` configuration file is a little cumbersome. There is no reason to have configuration options above the brackets enclosing the individual script for `messages` (as that can overwrite global config options depending on how they are read ) and you should move the `compress` and other flags into it.

Comment: There are some errors which i can check by my own, but you suggestion working perfectly.